# What is the equivalent of onPrepareOptionsMenu for support Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I know that if I have a support v7 Toolbar set on my Activity I can make changes to the overflow menu right before it is displayed by overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`

However I have a standalone support v7 Toolbar. I still want to display an overflow menu and be able to update it right before it is opened. I know how to display it...

```
Toolbar toolbar = ...
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO
        return false;
    }
});
```

... but how can I make changes right before the overflow menu is open?